# When a flowering plant isn't currently flowering, what is that state or phase called?

Tags: flowering

Is there a technical term for when a plant isn't a seedling, but isn't producing flowers, reproducing, or going dormant? If there are synonyms for that term, I'd love to know them as well.

As an example, say we have a plant that flowers late summer. But I'm interested in its appearance and habit from spring until it flowers, what do I search for? A common problem I find, is that most photos of plants are taken when they're fully in bloom. Look at an [image search for Prunus tenella](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1419&bih=946&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=RKxoWtepF8W7sQGLzafYAg&q=Prunus%20tenella&oq=Prunus%20tenella), as an example.

Comment: I usually add "trunk", "branch" or "leaves" on google image search. Wikipedia is also a good starting point (ev. interlink with Wiki-Common, where the image(draws) from old books are usually good for identification)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the vegetative state.

I know two identification flora about vegetative state:

- *Flora Vegetativa*: in French or German, of Swiss wild plants
- *The vegetative key to the British flora*

Answer (score 0):

Perennation? the survival of an individual over successive years, or of a dormant organ during unfavourable seasons. There's also dormancy, hibernation and senescence/senescent too however they over lap with descriptions. And I wouldn't use them describing a plant in this way. Although they are valid.
As VivdD has said, there are examples of specific plants that do just that, and just stop growing- however I did say I wouldn't use them describing a plant in that way! I seem to remember several types of desert plant that do just that and seem to die, and then spring back to life when conditions allow- their not dead nor alive- the problem is the explanations in main text are not exacting enough because there are many exemptions in the plant world. Its a very complicated subject and your always going to be caught out one minute and not the next.

Comment: "Dormancy" is completely wrong - the OP explicitely said "...when they are not going dormant...". The same for hibernation.